# Can I control inbound and outbound traffic to App Services on a VNET?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network, azure-app-service-envrmnt

Everything I have found thus far is pointing me to use [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic) to control traffic to my applications.

Basically I am trying to set up 2 subnets within my VNET, the front end subnet will contain an App Service that will be internet accessible over 80/443. The backend subnet will contain an App Service that will not be accessible to internet traffic over 80/443 but should allow traffic from the front end subnet over 80/443.

Is this possible without using the App Service Environment, if so what infrastructure would be required?

Comment: The App Service is never really "contained" in the subnet, it only makes a connection to the VNET.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve that using web.config file to control what traffic gets accepted by the webapp. This is the article to get you started:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/

So you would limit your backend to not accept traffic from anywhere except your frontend subnet

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible without using the App Service Environment, if so what infrastructure would be required?

The answer is no. Until now, without using the App Service Environment, we can't create a web app which hosted in a VNET. The web app is public facing and can't be internal accessed with a private IP address. So we also can't use a proxy which hosted in a VNET to restrict access to the web application.